# file system space

Tags: 10.04, disk-usage

I am on ubuntu vps server and I am running these problem always

```
  cannot create temp file for here-document: no space left on device
```

from days to days my server stop and the error shown to me that there is no disk space however I changed my space from 96 GB to 192 GB on linode servers

when I run df -h

```
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/xvda              47G   45G  1.6G  97% /
 devtmpfs              4.0G  112K  4.0G   1% /dev
 none                  4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
 none                  4.0G   48K  4.0G   1% /var/run
 none                  4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /var/lock
 none                  4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
```

when It becomes 0% available the problem was in my apache log files after I disabled the logs and removing it it becomes 96% and however I am checking the file space it grows

when I run df -i

```
 Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
 /dev/xvda            11300032 3933086 7366946   35% /
 devtmpfs             1026040    2094 1023946    1% /dev
 none                 1026334       1 1026333    1% /dev/shm
 none                 1026334      26 1026308    1% /var/run
 none                 1026334       2 1026332    1% /var/lock
 none                 1026334       1 1026333    1% /lib/init/rw
```

how can I increase the available free space and I can use from the rest of my 192 GB